# how do i select a variable from the eclipse variables view

Tags: eclipse, debugging, variables, testing

I'm developsing a debugger plugin in eclipse; i'm trying to write unit tests to grep vars from the variables view and test thier values.

so far I was able to retrieve the variables view object as an IViewPart;
I've extracted the selection provider related to the variables view, by doing this:

```
ISelectionProvider selProvider = viewPart.getSite().getSelectionProvider();
```

now i would like to set a selection on the first element in the variables view

how do i get the elements list, or select any of the elements?

Thanks in advance,
Anat

Comment: Why aren't you using the extensive [Debug API](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2Fmodel%2Fpackage-summary.html) provided by Eclipse?

Comment: I'm aware of the debug API, but i need a way to go over the list of debug element inside the variables view; i need the list first, than i can extract the IVariables from it, i suppose.